# Combining Update Queries in 1 SQL statement

Tags: sql, union, updates

I am trying to combine two update queries into one sql statement. I thought I could use a union query to combine the queries but I was not able to. Any advice? The queries I want to combine are as follows:

```
UPDATE PromotionDatabase
  SET PromotionDatabase.PromotionWeekEndingSunday = [PromotionDatabase]![Start Date]+-(Weekday([PromotionDatabase]![Start Date])-1)+7 

UPDATE PromotionDatabase
  SET PromotionDatabase.PromotionEndingWeekEndingSunday = [PromotionDatabase]![End Date]+-(Weekday([PromotionDatabase]![End Date])-1)+7;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? That syntax looks really strange with the `!` inside the identifer.

Comment: I was astonished by the `+-` operator ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to update 2 fields in the same UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE PromotionDatabase
SET PromotionWeekEndingSunday = [Start Date]+-(Weekday([Start Date])-1)+7,
   PromotionEndingWeekEndingSunday = [End Date]+-(Weekday([End Date])-1)+7;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an update is the following.  See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```